# Postgres is inserting '$,?' in place of texts in my address field of the table. Is it some encoding issue or something else?

Tags: postgresql, encoding

I have a customer table on my PostgreSQL database with columns related to customer information like name , address etc. My problem is when I insert texts in the table, they are getting saved as `$ , ?` symbols. It's not with all the characters but with few only.

Comment: If it is literally `$` and `?`, it must be your application that is mangling the input. Otherwise, you have to set `client_encoding` properly.

Comment: "MAIN BAZAR  TA: JAMKHAMBHALIA&#10;SHETHABHADSAR - 361306  Jamnagar Gujarat&#10;India". This is the text which i saved in addres field. You can see "&#" in between.

Comment: Oh, that's your application or something else in your stack converting characters to *HTML escape sequences*. It has nothing to do with PostgreSQL.